# How to create own multi-currency crypto-wallet?

Tags: ethereum, bitcoin, wallet

I want to create my own cryptocurrency wallet. I know about private and public key concept which is used in the wallet but I could not understand how my wallet verified other public address? How my wallet verified other users? How coinomi manage their wallet to store all kind of currency? Can anyone explain the full logic of wallet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is hierarchical deterministic wallets (or "HD Wallets"). These wallets were proposed as part of [bip32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki). Further along with [bip39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki), [bip43](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0043.mediawiki) and [bip44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki), you can create a full fledged HD wallet.

1. Bip32: This proposes the specifications of HD wallets. It contains all the technical details like how a HD wallet should be implemented. It describes how a single seed of chosen length (between 128 and 512 bits; 256 bits is advised) can be used to generate number of keys for various accounts of different cryptocurrencies in unique as well as deterministic ways.
2. Bip39: It proposes a scheme to encode the seed into human readable passphrase of 12 (or 15/18/21/24) words.
3. Bip43: The BIP32 specification offers implementors too many degrees of freedom. Multiple implementations may claim they are BIP32 compatible, but in fact they can produce wallets with different logical structures making them non-interoperable. This situation unfortunately renders "BIP32 compatible" statement rather useless. Hence, , Bip43 was introduced.
4. Bip44: This contains the actual implementation details of HD wallets.

**What are wallets?**

In layman terms, they are very much like your physical wallets which helps in storing money. However, since cryptocurrencies are more like digital currencies, wallets required to store (read manage) them are also kind of digital.
Now, there are 2 kinds of wallets.

1. Hardware wallets
2. Software wallets

As mentioned earlier, crypto wallets do not actually store the cryptocurrencies. Like banks, the ownership details of the cryptocurrencies lie on the ledger which in case of cryptos is the Blockchain. Now, these digital wallets are only used to manage them. Further, this management means it gives you an exclusive right to spend your own cryptocurrencies. 
Now, cryptos are affiliated to some accounts like we have our digital money in our bank accounts. In order to manage that digital money, we have been provided various facilities like internet banking, credit cards etc using which we can spend that money. Similarly, for spending cryptos, we need wallets.

So, Wallets are nothing more than a wrapper around some digital keys. They are more like your internet banking credentials or a 4-digit pin of your credit card. To see, how an ethereum wallet looks like, checkout [this](https://medium.com/blockchain-ethereum/ethereum-wallet-how-does-it-look-like-93f75b282108) article.

**What are HD wallets?**

Now, after bitcoin boom, there came a flood of cryptos. Now, to manage each kind of cryptos, a different account was required which had their individual keys. Further, within same crypto domain, one owns hundreds of accounts with their individual keys. So to manage various keys from various domains using their individual wallets was becoming pretty difficult. Further, once you create a wallet with some vendor, it was impossible to migrate it some other vendor as each vendor implements the wallet structure as per his whims and fancies. Hence, wallet portability was becoming a huge issue. To solve all these problems, HD wallets were introduced.

For some detailed explanation of bips, you can either refer their corresponding github wikis or you can refer these articles [here](https://medium.com/bitcraft/so-you-want-to-build-an-ethereum-hd-wallet-cb2b7d7e4998) and [here](https://medium.com/bitcraft/hd-wallets-explained-from-high-level-to-nuts-and-bolts-9a41545f5b0).

**Edit:** For implemetation, you can use libraries. For e.g. if you are using JavaScript, you can use [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet). [Here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet/blob/86464c91ae64cb440b22760d992ba5df3aa8e8ba/index.js#L18) is a constructor function to create a v3 wallet object. For creating a HD wallet, you can use [this](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet/blob/86464c91ae64cb440b22760d992ba5df3aa8e8ba/hdkey.js#L16).

Now, the question comes how to use it. Well for that you can refer any standard Ethereum wallet. Better place to start could be exploring the code of [metamask-extension](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension) which is completely reliant on ethereumjs-wallet library.